# ANTLR: Grammar with uppercase rules won't recognize input

Tags: parsing, antlr, rule

I'm quite new to ANTLR and I need an explanation about its behaviour when recognising input string. From what I understood, rules staring by an uppercase letter are lexer rules while the ones starting by lowercase letter are parser rules.
I have the following language and I need to write the grammar accordingly:
[image: language]
So L should accept all the strings composed by:

- non empty string with b and/or c
- d
- non empty string with a and/or c

This is the first grammar I wrote and I don't have problems with it when recognising the input `bbbcbcbcbcdaaacacacaaaa`:

```
start   : (alfa 'd' beta);

alfa    : ('b'|'c') | ('b'|'c') alfa;
beta    : ('a'|'c') | ('a'|'c') beta;

WS      : (' '|'\n'|'\t'|'\r')->skip;
```

But if I change it like the following one, the same string is not recognised anymore (below you can see the debugger result of ANTLRWorks):

[image]

```
start   : (alfa 'd' beta);

alfa    : ALFA_VALS | ALFA_VALS alfa;
beta    : BETA_VALS | BETA_VALS beta;

ALFA_VALS: ('b'|'c');
BETA_VALS: ('a'|'c');
WS      : (' '|'\n'|'\t'|'\r')->skip;
```

Furthermore, if I change `ALFA_VALS` and `BETA_VALS` to `alfa_vals` and `beta_vals` respectively, no problems occur.

Could someone provide me an explanation about this behaviour? Because I couldn't find a specific one addressing this problem.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I recommend you use ANTLR v4 instead of the old v3 you're using now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANTLR lexer matches the longest possible sub-sequence of input, or if it can match the same input using multiple lexer rules, it uses the first rule that matches.

The lexer knows no context and no parser state, and decides based solely on the characters on input.

If you define `ALFA_VALS` and `BETA_VALS` in lexer this way, the input `'c'` will *always* be matched as `ALFA_VALS` token.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! So, which alternative do I have when dealing with same chars in different lexer rules? Or is it correct to transform them in parser rules?

Comment: Whenever you need a context to determine what the input means, leave it up to parser. Lexer is used to tokenize the input into parts that are themselves atomic to the parser. You could make tokens for `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`. If `'c'` can mean two different things to parser, you need to leave the decision of what it means (here "alfa" or "beta") up to the parser.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a slightly different approach? Your right recursive definition is rather untypical for ANTLR (while very often used in bottom-up parsers). Instead use the simpler expressions as defined in your language:

```
grammar Example;

start   : (α D β) EOF;

α: (B | C)+;
β: (A | C)+;

A: 'a';
B: 'b';
C: 'c';
D: 'd';

WS: (' '|'\n'|'\t'|'\r') -> skip;
```

Which gives you this simpler and more natural parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Mike, how do you get a nice looking graph like that? I hope it works on windows.

Comment: That's part of my [ANTLR4 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) for Visual Studio Code (which is a cross platform editor).